# Set selection range in the Visual Studio Code document

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a command in an extension, before run the command, I want to change the selection range to get the whole lines...

```
const sel = textEditor.selection;
const firstLine = textEditor.document.lineAt(sel.start.line);
const lastLine = textEditor.document.lineAt(sel.end.line);

const range = new vscode.Range(firstLine.lineNumber, firstLine.range.start.character, lastLine.lineNumber, lastLine.range.end.character);
```

I've created a new range, but I don't know how to set the selection of the document to a new range...

Comment: `textEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(firstLine.lineNumber, firstLine.range.start.character, lastLine.lineNumber, lastLine.range.end.character)` ?

Comment: It works, I don't know why, but I thought that `textEditor.selection` was readonly... I used `textEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(range.start, range.end);` instead, to simplify the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Selection()` has 2 overloads (2 or 4 arguments):

1. `Selection(anchor: vscode.Position, active: vscode.Position)`
2. `Selection(anchorLine: number, anchorCharacter: number, activeLine: number, activeCharacter: number)`

Example, using 4 arguments:

```
textEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(firstLine.lineNumber, firstLine.range.start.character, 
lastLine.lineNumber, lastLine.range.end.character)
```

---

To make multiple cursors you need to set `textEditor.selections`

```js
textEditor.selections = [
    new vscode.Selection(0, 0, 0, 10),
    new vscode.Selection(1, 0, 1, 10),
];
```

Comment: how do you set the selection for multiple cursors? -- Looping through the selections collection and setting those doesn't work (nothing happens).

Comment: Note, that looping through and updating the selection array has no effect. You need to create a new array. E.g. after looping you could do `editor.selections = [...editor.selections]`

Answer (score 1):

For registering a command for setting the cursor position, i used this :

```
let cmd = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('extension.mysnippet', (te) => {
  // selection start = line 3, char 5 ||| selection end = line 3, char 5
  te.selection = new vscode.Selection(5, 3, 5, 3)
});
context.subscriptions.push(cmd);
```