# How to get current text/symbol when implementing Go To Definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm working on my first vscode extension using Language Server Protocol, I need to get the text were the `Right click -> Go to definition` was triggered

[image]

My current `onDefinition` method receives only the `textPosition`

```
export default class DefinitionFinder extends Handler {
    constructor(
        protected connection: Connection,
        private refManager: ReferenceManager)
    {
        super();

        this.connection.onDefinition(async (textPosition) => {
            return this.handleErrors(
                this.getDefinition(textPosition), undefined) as Promise<Definition>;
        });
    }
    
private async getDefinition(textPosition: TextDocumentPositionParams): Promise<Location[]> {
    const text = "funABC";

    // instead of hardcoded value I need to get the text/symbol 
    // that is going to be use to go to definition 

    return this.refManager.getDefinitionLocations(text);
}
```

The `TextDocumentPositionParams` only contains the `documentUri`, `line(number)` and `character(number)`

Does that mean that on each call to `onDefinition` I need to open the document, go to the line and character and get the current word ?

```
export interface TextDocumentPositionParams {
    /**
     * The text document.
     */
    textDocument: TextDocumentIdentifier;
    /**
     * The position inside the text document.
     */
    position: Position;
}

export interface TextDocumentIdentifier {
    /**
     * The text document's uri. (string)
     */
    uri: DocumentUri;
}

export declare namespace Position {
    /**
     * Creates a new Position literal from the given line and character.
     * @param line The position's line.
     * @param character The position's character.
     */
```

Comment: It seems that it has to be done by hand - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up implementing the logic to get the word/symbol when "Go To Definition" is requested on a Language Server

I decided to return a LocationLink which also appears as a hyperlink over the word/symbol

```js
this.connection.onDefinition(async (textPosition) => {
    return this.handleErrors(
        this.getDefinitionLink(textPosition), undefined) as Promise<LocationLink[]>;
});
```

This method get the symbol from the document and then look its definition in the refManager

```js
private async getDefinitionLink(textPosition: TextDocumentPositionParams): Promise<LocationLink[]> {
    const symbol = this.getSymbolAtPosition(textPosition.position, textPosition.textDocument.uri);

    return this.refManager.getDefinitionLink(symbol);
}
```

This is the actual logic to extract the current word no matter if it was click in the middle of it.

```js
let TokenSeparatorsXML = /[\t= <>"]/;

public getSymbolAtPosition(position: Position, documentUri: string): string {
    const range = {
        start: { line: position.line, character: 0},
        end: { line: position.line, character: Number.MAX_VALUE  }
    };
    //get the whole line 
    const txtDoc = this.refManager.getDocument(documentUri)!;

    const context = txtDoc.getText(range);
    const offset = position.character ;

    let start = offset-1;

    while ((start > 0) && !context[start].match(this.TokenSeparatorsXML))
    {
        start--;
    }

    let end = offset;

    while ((end < context.length) && !context[end].match(this.TokenSeparatorsXML))
    {
        end++;
    }

    const symbol = context.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);

    console.log(`${start}->${end}- symbol: ${symbol}`);

    return symbol;
}
```

In my case the token separators are very narrow but you should consider using the word pattern https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#word-pattern

The full code of the extension can be found here - https://github.com/mauriciogracia/petrel-xml

Answer (score 1):

Language servers usually maintain a text document cache based on the document change events they receive. If you're writing the language server in TypeScript, you can simply use the implementation from the `vscode-languageserver` and `vscode-languageserver-textdocument` packages. Relevant excerpts from the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts):

```ts
import { TextDocuments } from 'vscode-languageserver';
import { TextDocument } from 'vscode-languageserver-textdocument';

// Create a simple text document manager.
const documents: TextDocuments<TextDocument> = new TextDocuments(TextDocument);

...

// Make the text document manager listen on the connection
// for open, change and close text document events
documents.listen(connection);
```

Then you can just do:

```ts
documents.get(uri).getText(range)
```

Comment: thanks this helps me out, but how do I calculate the range, given that the cursor can be in middle of a word, do I need to tokenize the document line or what is the approach ?

Comment: I'd simply get the relevant line and find the word boundaries with a regex. If you were using the VSCode API and `getWordRangeAtPosition()`, that's what VSCode would do internally anyway (using the language's "word pattern" https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#word-pattern).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I implemented this:

```
let word = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
```

This works for the extension API

Comment: Thanks, my document is of type `TextDocument` from `vscode-languageserver-textdocument` and does not contain that method `getWordRangeAtPosition`, any ideas why ?

Comment: That's because that method is from VSCode's text document API, which is a different thing than `vscode-languageserver` package .

Comment: ok, but how do I use it ? do I need to cast the TextDocument to something else ?